# LSTM accuracy doesn't change no matter what I do

Tags: python, keras, classification, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I'm implementing my first Neural Network, it being an LSTM for binary sentiment analysis classification. I've pre-processed the data with lowering the letters, tokenizing and removing most punctuation (keeping only .,').
I'm also using GloVe's 100d pre-trained embeddings for this.

The problem is: Whatever I do the accuracy is terrible and doesn't change with epocs (also doesn't change when changing the LSTM architecture)

I've tried changing the optimizer and its learning rate, adding more neurons to the LSTM, changing number of epochs and batch size.

Nothing seems to work

```py
def setLSTM(data, stopRem, stemm, lemma, negHand):
    #pre-processing data
    data = pre_processing(data, stopRem, stemm, lemma, negHand)
    print(data[1])


    #splitting data
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = datasplit(data)

    #Setting the words as unique indexes (max 10k unique indexes)
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=5000)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X_train)
    X_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_train)
    X_test = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X_test)

    #getting vocabulary
    vocab = tokenizer.word_index.items()
    print(vocab)
    vocab_size = vocab_size = len(tokenizer.word_index) + 1

    #maxlen = Maxlen is correspondes to the maximum tweet length (so that we can add padding to shorter ones)
    maxlen = len(max((X_train + X_test)))
    print("Maxlen is: ",maxlen)

    #Padding the sequences to guarantee that all tweets have the same length
    X_train = pad_sequences(X_train, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
    X_test = pad_sequences(X_test, padding='post', maxlen=maxlen)
    #Create embedding matrix with zeros (because some of the vocabulary might not exist in the embeddings)
    #and adding the embeddings we have
    embedding_matrix = zeros((vocab_size, 100))
    for idx,word in vocab:
        embedding_vector = embeddings.get(word)
        if embedding_vector is not None:
            embedding_matrix[idx] = embedding_vector

    #creating the model with its layers (embedding layer, lstm layer, dense layer)
    model = Sequential()
    #The embedding layer has "trainable=False" because we're using pre-trained embeddings
    embedding_layer = Embedding(vocab_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=maxlen, trainable=False)
    model.add(embedding_layer)
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #Adding an LSTM layer with 128 neurons
    model.add(LSTM(units=100))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    #Adding dense layer with sigmoid activation
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    #opt = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
    #Compiling model ("loss='binary_crossentropy'" because we're dealing with a binary classification problem)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
    print(model.summary())

    history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=64, epochs=5, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
    score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=1)

    print("Test Score:", score[0])
    print("Test Accuracy:", score[1])



setLSTM(tweets,False,False,False,False)
```

```
Model: "sequential_9"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_9 (Embedding)      (None, 13, 100)           1916600   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 13, 100)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_9 (LSTM)                (None, 100)               80400     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 100)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 101       
=================================================================
Total params: 1,997,101
Trainable params: 80,501
Non-trainable params: 1,916,600
_________________________________________________________________
None
Train on 10852 samples, validate on 2713 samples

Epoch 1/5
10852/10852 [==============================] - 5s 448us/step - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5275 - val_loss: 0.6916 - val_acc: 0.5404

Epoch 2/5
10852/10852 [==============================] - 4s 360us/step - loss: 0.6917 - acc: 0.5286 - val_loss: 0.6908 - val_acc: 0.5404

Epoch 3/5
10852/10852 [==============================] - 4s 365us/step - loss: 0.6920 - acc: 0.5286 - val_loss: 0.6907 - val_acc: 0.5404

Epoch 4/5
10852/10852 [==============================] - 4s 382us/step - loss: 0.6916 - acc: 0.5286 - val_loss: 0.6903 - val_acc: 0.5404

Epoch 5/5
10852/10852 [==============================] - 4s 383us/step - loss: 0.6916 - acc: 0.5264 - val_loss: 0.6906 - val_acc: 0.5404

4522/4522 [==============================] - 1s 150us/step
Test Score: 0.6925433831950933
Test Accuracy: 0.5176913142204285
```

Comment: You should try normalizing your data. You can do it easily by using `X_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(X_train, axis=1)`

Comment: Thank for the answer, I'm afraid the results stay unchanged

Comment: UPDATE:

For anyone with the same issue, there were many problems:

I was calculating the maxlen wrongly

I was creating the embedding matrix with " for idx,word in vocab:" but it should be "for word,idx in vocab"

Not in the code here: I was only getting the first dimension represented in the embeddings

So basically I wasn't feeding the LSTM anything but arrays of 0's.
After fixing those issues it's working fine.

Cheers.

Comment: It'd be good if you could post a self-answer, if you've worked it out, showing the corrected working code.